# How to name a thread running a Task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I find naming threads to be very useful when debugging.

I can see no way to name a thread using arguments to `Task.Factory.StartNew()`

So is it acceptable to name the thread explicitly in the task? eg:

```
private void MyFunc()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Foobulizer";
        Foobulize();
    });
}
```

However, I appreciate that threads may be reused for different tasks, so would I need to explicitly reset the thread name at the end of the task? This feels pretty hacky so I'm thinking this is probably a bad idea, or there's a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot do this since multiple Tasks can share the same or multiple threads depending on ThreadPool state in a given moment of time. Basically, Task is not a Thread. It's just a high level abstraction for the asynchronous operation. You can use the [Task.Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.id.aspx) property, but keep in mind that `Id` is readonly and of `int` type, so you can't assign custom user-friendly name.

> Task IDs are assigned on-demand and do not necessarily represent the
> order in the which Task instances were created

Take a look at the built-in Visual Studio 2010 Parallel Debugging features. Perhaps you'll find another approach: [Walkthrough: Debugging a Parallel Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554943(VS.100).aspx)

Parallel Tasks Window:

[image]

> For each running Task, you can read its ID, which is returned by the
> same-named property, the ID and name of the thread that runs it, its
> location (hovering over that displays a tooltip that has the whole
> call stack). Also, under the Task column, you can see the method that
> was passed into the task; in other words, the starting point

Comment: You can use on code as `Task.CurrentId` on relevant Task Action or method.

Answer (score 9):

The default `TaskScheduler` uses the .NET `ThreadPool` to schedule the tasks. So you will get a thread that already exists or one that will be reused (both potentially, but likely).

Note that you can only name a thread once in .NET 5 and earlier versions. The second attempt to call `Thread.CurrentThread.Name` will raise an [`InvalidOperationException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.name#exceptions). This is particularly bad when it is a thread pool thread.

In general you should not change attributes of a thread that you did not (explicitly) create or own (the name being one, the [priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.priority) being the other prominent candidates).

Answer (score -4):

Sure you can, just remove the Name again when you're done. set the thread Name again to "Idle" ore string.Empty after Foobulize();